# changing a value using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function

I am trying to change/set a value using javascript.

From what I have currently created this works for a piece of text in  tags going by the id: title.

It works like this:

```js
function change() {

  var myNewTitle = document.getElementById('myTextField').value;
  if (myNewTitle.length == 0) {
    alert('Write Some real Text please.');
    return;
  }

  var title = document.getElementById('title');
  title.innerHTML = myNewTitle;

}
```

```html
<h1 id="title">test</h1>
<input type="text" id="myTextField" />
<input type="submit" id="byBtn" value="Change" onclick="change()" />
```

Now what I want to set is a value inside here:

```
Voornaam + Achternaam:<input type="text" name="firstname" value="" />
```

Which is basically supposed to be a firstname.
I want the value to be set, using the method I was already using for my  tag. 
However when I give it an id like so:

```
Voornaam + Achternaam:<input type="text" id="firstname" value="" />
```

And also change my function change to that id instead of title, it doesn't change or set the value inside the firstname field.

could anybody help me out?

Comment: May you add a [mcve] of the problem? The example you have given works perfectly.

Comment: Huh? You want another `textbox` to be populated with the value from another `textbox` when clicking a button?

Comment: could you share your html whichs not work as you want

Comment: You might have misunderstood me, the example given does work. Although what I want it do exactly is something else and something I cannot figure out.

Comment: @KevinBosman Your code works buddy, I don't see any problem. Please explain yourself ([You can see it working here](http://jsbin.com/wanuginifo/edit?html,js,output))

Comment: Let me explain myself a bit better here, excuse me if I've not explained well enough. The <h1> tag indeed does get changed. However I have a textfield. Which is: Voornaam + Achternaam:<input type="text" id="firstname" value="" />. i want the value of that to be changed, not the <h1> tag. but I can't seem to figure that out.

Comment: @KevinBosman change to what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I don't understand why you want one input to update another , if you want to change the value of an input field you must use `.value` instead of `.innerHTML`

```js
function change() {

  var myNewTitle = document.getElementById('myTextField').value;
  if (myNewTitle.length == 0) {
    alert('Write Some real Text please.');
    return;
  }

  var title = document.getElementById('firstname');
  title.value = myNewTitle;

}
```

```html
<h1 id="title">test</h1>
Voornaam + Achternaam:<input type="text" id="firstname" value="" />
<br/><br/>
<input type="text" id="myTextField" />
<input type="submit" id="byBtn" value="Change" onclick="change()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You set the `value` attribute on an element with the `value` key:

```
var firstnameInput = document.getElementById('firstname');
firstnameInput.value = 'Firstname value';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this:
Use `firstname.value = myNewTitle;` instead of `innerHTML`.

```js
function change() {

  var myNewTitle = document.getElementById('myTextField').value;
  if (myNewTitle.length == 0) {
    alert('Write Some real Text please.');
    return;
  }

  var firstname = document.getElementById('firstname');
  firstname.value = myNewTitle;

}
```

```html
<h1 id="title">test</h1>
<input type="text" id="myTextField" />
<input type="submit" id="byBtn" value="Change" onclick="change()" />
Voornaam + Achternaam:<input type="text" id="firstname" value = ""/>
```